# Are there any problems opening a helipad close to an airport?

Tags: helicopter, usa, airspace, rotorcraft, helipad

I am looking at the possibility of installing a helipad at my house which is within 1.5 miles of a Class D airport. The location is not in the approach to any of the runways, however.

I am not a rotorcraft guy, so I am wondering if having a helipad this close to an airport will cause any issues?

(note that the whole area is Class B airspace, so it will always require a clearance to take off)

Comment: Is this is for Sweden or Canada?

Comment: @mins yeah, yeah, very funny.

Comment: Unless you are within the inner ring of the Class-B you don't need a clearance to take off VFR if you stay below the Class-B shelf... Out of curiosity, why, not being a rotorcraft guy, would you want to have a helipad on your property? Probably won't do you any favors with the neighbors.

Answer (score 4):

In the US, normally it is not a problem.  I would talk with the tower supervisor, to see if a planner could be consulted before you go too far down the road and start paving or something like that.

A good place to start would be a memorandum of understanding, where you and the FAA would work out the operations out of the field, and discuss arrival and departure coordination.

I could come up with a list of twenty heliports within 1.5 miles of Class C or D airports. Funny how hospitals end up near airports. Ditto for police facilities.

Life is easier if you do not plan on trying to get instrument approaches.